# Colocar class Active em um menu dinâmico com JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Eu criei um arquivo menu-controller.js, que ele é responsável por pegar o menu na minha API e gerar dinamicamente nas minhas páginas HTML que eu quiser usa-lo.

Porém, eu preciso que, quando o usuário clique em alguma opção do menu, ele fique com o efeito do CSS `:active`. Alguém poderia me explicar como eu consigo fazer isso?

menu-controller.js

```
const MenuController = (function () {

    let integration = new MenuIntegration({});

    const menu = function() {

        return sessionStorage.getItem("menu");

    };

    const init = function () {

        if (!menu()) {

            const menuArr = integration.getMenu();
            sessionStorage.setItem("menu", percorreMenu(menuArr));

        }

        $(".main-menu").html(menu());
    }

    function percorreMenu (menuArr)  {
        var menu = ""; 
        for (i = 0; i < menuArr.length; i++){
            let menuItem =  menuArr[i];
            menu += 
            `<li class="item-menu active">
                    <a href="${menuItem.link}"><i class="zmdi ${menuItem.icon}"></i> ${menuItem.label}</a>
            </li>`;   
        }

        $('.item-menu').click(function(e) {
            $('.item-menu').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
          });

          // verificar via JS:
          const href = [location.pathname, location.search].join('?');
          $('.item-menu[href="' + href + '"]').addClass('active');

        return menu;

    }

    return {
        init: init
    }

})();

$(document).ready(function () {
    MenuController.init();
});
```

Comment: `:active` é uma pseudo-classe, você não pode aplicá-la num elemento. Assim como `: hover`, é ativada a partir de um evento, um click por exemplo. No seu código, você está adicionando e removendo uma classe chamada "active", o que está perfeito, basta você colocar o estilo desejado nessa classe

Comment: Vc tem que fazer um CSS para o ".active" tipo `.active {color:red}` o `:active` é o estado do elemento quando ele está sendo pressionado com o mouse, e ".active" é apenas um nome para a classe que vc vai adicionar no elemento, e o estilo dela precisa ser construído no CSS,

Comment: Obrigado galera, consegui ajeitar!!